# Can I add some information to resource in payload token by Keycloak?

Tags: jwt, keycloak, access-token

Can I add some information to resource in payload token by Keycloak?
I use keycloak for taking jwt. Token have roles assigned to some resource, f.e.

```
"resource_access": {
    "subject-service": {
      "roles": [
        "ADMIN"
      ]
    },
    "account-service": {
      "roles": [
        "USER",
        
      ]
    }
  }
```

But I would like to add some attributes to resource and used it on backend or frontend.
I would like to assign permissions based on the data in the token f.e.:

```
   "resource_access": {
        "subject-service": {
          "roles": [
            "ADMIN"
          ],
          "attribute1":[read,write,delete],
          "attribute2":[read],
          "attribute3":[write]
    
        },
        "account-service": {
          "roles": [
            "USER",
            
          ],
          "attribut1":[write],
        }
      }
```

Can I do it by Keycloak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without doing your custom Mapper, you will not be able to achieve the format.
However, out of the box you add Keycloak custom Mappers. For that go to:

- Select your `realm`;
- Go to `clients`;
- Select the `client` that you are going to request the token against;
- Go to `Mappers`;
- Click Create
- In `Mapper type` select `Hardcoded claim`;
- Fill up the rest accordingly.

For instance for:

```
      "attribute1":[read,write,delete],
      "attribute2":[read],
      "attribute3":[write]
```

would be:

- `Token Claim Name` : Resource1
- `Claim value` : `"{attribute1:[read,write,delete], attribute2:[read], attribute3:[write]}"`
- `Claim JSON Type` : `JSON`

And the token:

```
{
  (..)
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      (..)
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account-service": {
      "roles": [
       (..)
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        (...)
      ]
    }
  },
  (...)
    "Resource1": "{
          attribute1:[read,write,delete], 
          attribute2:[read], 
          attribute3:[write]
     }"
}
```